# Query Formula Google Sheets Date & other conditions

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Hello Brilliant People!

I have a spreadsheet with the following column headers:  student ID, student name, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, 9/13, 9/14, 9/15...9/30. The dates are populated with A for Absent and P for Present. The M, T, W, Th, F columns are populated with the course the student has for second period on that specific day (it's different every day).

I would like to query this data to return the following:

If today were a Monday, it would return the student ID, student name, and the course the student has for second period (Monday column) and the just the students who are absent for that date.

If today were a Tuesday, it would return the student ID, student name, the course the student has for second period (Tuesday column) and just the students who are absent for that date.

Same for W, Th, & F. Tried lots of different things, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It's quite easy by combining the source encapsulated by curly brackets, then match the criteria with the headers and tranform the valueX in ColX. Shar a simplified copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: The dashboard tab has the raw data. And the Desired Output tab is an example of what I'd like to automatically produce without copying/pasting! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spnsQ99Nqa1xVYYIlAXU5J65HZniLxDbuxFrooYUqrc/edit#gid=399371361

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query({Dashboard!A1:U},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col"& (MATCH(today(),Dashboard!1:1,0)) &",Col4,Col"& (MATCH(choose(weekday(today(),2),"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),Dashboard!1:1,0)) &" where Col"& (MATCH(today(),Dashboard!1:1,0)) &"='A' ",1)
```

in this formula

- `(MATCH(today(),Dashboard!1:1,0))` will give you the column where you can find the date,
- and `(MATCH(choose(weekday(today(),2),"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),Dashboard!1:1,0))` the column where you can find the day of week.

[take a copy of the spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ddknZFG9NisvmpeOLgfF1xmurWMGJp6O5XsrzsjO-bQ/edit?usp=sharing)